# Push notification icons are displaying very tiny in Marshmallow devices in Android

Tags: android, notifications

I am using the Code:

```
/** Prepare the notification UI **/
    private void prepareNotificationUI(String mTitle, String mDescription, int notificationId, Bundle bundle) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        intent.setAction(Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
        // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder
                .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                        | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);



        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationHelper notificationHelper = new NotificationHelper(getApplicationContext());
            nb = notificationHelper.getNotification(pendingIntent, mTitle, mDescription);
            if (nb != null) {
                notificationHelper.notify(notificationId, nb);
            }
        }else {

            Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            String channelId = mContext.getString(R.string.app_name);

            Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.notification_icon);


            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channelId);
            //Notification.Builder notificationBuilder=new Notification.Builder(mContext);

            notificationBuilder.setContentTitle(mTitle);
            notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(mDescription));
            notificationBuilder.setContentText(mDescription);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
                notificationBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white));
                notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
            } else {
                notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
                notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
            }

            /*notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon);
            notificationBuilder.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.white));*/
            notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
            notificationBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
            notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.WHITE, 3000, 3000);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());

        }

    }
```

---

- I am getting the icon very tiny in Marshmellow devices. It works fine
  in other devices
- Earlier the icon was not displaying at all in Marshmellow. Then I
  added the code below. Icons are displaying but size is tiny

  notificationBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);

Comment: What's the dimensions of `R.drawable.notification_icon`?

Comment: @Florescu Cătălin .... Should we need to Maintain any proper `dimention-ratio`

Comment: Is that a question or an affirmation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
 Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        } else {
            notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        }
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Hope this may help you

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawable icon use mipmap icon, it worked for me.

```
Bitmap bigIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(),
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```